# MySQL: get json objects with unknown key name

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I'm stuck trying to filter for entries that only have one json object with their corresponding value. My data includes nested json and several different keys which I don't know the names of. Any help would be appreciated!

approach

```
SELECT
jt.`field` AS `field_name`, JSON_LENGTH(column), JSON_VALUES(column,CONCAT("'$.",jt.`field`,"'"))
FROM
table,
JSON_TABLE(
JSON_KEYS(column),
'$[*]' COLUMNS(`field` VARCHAR(191) PATH '$')) AS jt
where JSON_LENGTH(column)=1
```

table entries

```
{"key1": "2022-06-22", "key2": "2022-06-25"}
{"key12": "2022-06-21"}
{"key13": {"key131": "2022-06-01"}}
```

desired output

```
1:key12,1,"2022-06-21"
2:key13.key131,1,"2022-06-01"
```

Comment: Why 1st row does not produce the output row? What if the object is `{"key13": {"key131": "2022-06-01","key132": "2022-06-02"}}`? it matches `where JSON_LENGTH(column)=1`...

Comment: I am filtering for entries with only 1 object each. Since the first one has two objects, it would be skipped.

Comment: *Since the first one has two objects* First value is one object, and this object have two properties. And what about the object where nested sub-object have more than one property?

Comment: In theory you need in recursive CTE. It will parse the value by one nested level per iteration and collect the path up to JSON_DEPTH = 1. Finally only the rows where no multi-properties were found in the parsing chain should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I got working on MySQL 8.0.29:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (   
  SELECT mytable.id, jt.`field` AS `field_name`,     
    JSON_LENGTH(mycolumn) AS `len`, 
    JSON_EXTRACT(mytable.mycolumn, CONCAT('$."', jt.`field`, '"')) AS mycolumn   
  FROM mytable CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( 
    JSON_KEYS(mycolumn), 
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(`field` VARCHAR(191) PATH '$')
  ) AS jt 
  WHERE JSON_LENGTH(mycolumn)=1   
  UNION   
  SELECT cte.id, CONCAT(cte.field_name, '.', jt.`field`),     
    JSON_LENGTH(cte.mycolumn), 
    JSON_EXTRACT(cte.mycolumn, CONCAT('$."', jt.`field`, '"')) AS mycolumn   
  FROM cte CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( 
    JSON_KEYS(mycolumn), 
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(`field` VARCHAR(191) PATH '$')
  ) AS jt    
  WHERE JSON_TYPE(cte.mycolumn) = 'OBJECT' 
) 
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE JSON_TYPE(mycolumn)='STRING';
```

Output:

```
+------+--------------+------+--------------+
| id   | field_name   | len  | mycolumn     |
+------+--------------+------+--------------+
|    2 | key12        |    1 | "2022-06-21" |
|    3 | key13.key131 |    1 | "2022-06-01" |
+------+--------------+------+--------------+
```